# switching two nodes in a linked list

Tags: c++, list, object, linked-list

I'm fairly new to programming and I have this assignment, the goal is to print out 0123456789 then 9876543210 using these functions

```
bool List::SortSwap()
{
    bool doswap = true;
    ListElement *i =this-> head;
    ListElement *prev =this-> head;
    ListElement *b = i->next;

    while (doswap= true) {
        for (i; i != NULL; i = i->next) {
            if (i != this-> head) {
                prev->next = i;
            }
            if (i->value < b->value) {
                swap(prev, i, b);
                doswap = true;
            }
        }

        doswap= false;
    }

    return doswap;
} 


void List::swap(ListElement * prev, ListElement * a, ListElement * b)
{
    prev->next = b;
    b->next = a;
}
```

so if doswap is true it should go though my linked list and swap the elements if the value of it is less than the one that follows, when I run the program nothing happens my list wont print to the screen

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Draw the relevant nodes and their current connections. One-by-one move the connections to their new state. Write code that carries out the connection moves you had to make.

Answer (score 2):

If `b` is the successor of `a` and `a` the successor of `prev` than you have to place `b` as successor of `prev` and `a` as successor of `b`, to exchange `a` and `b`:

```
void List::swap( ListElement * prev, ListElement * a, ListElement * b)
{
    a->next = b->next; // put successor of b in place of succesor of a
    b->next = a;       // put a in place of successor of b
    prev->next = b;    // put b in place of succesor of prev
}
```

To swap elements sequential for a list, you have to handle the first two elements of list the first. So the rest of the list step by step. Terminate if you reach the predecesor of the last list element.

```
bool List::SortSwap()
{
    if ( head == nullptr || head->next == nullptr )
        return false;

    bool anySwapped = false;
    // hadle head of list and its successor
    if ( head->value < head->next->value )
    {
        ListElement *temp = head;
        head = head->next;       // successor of head becomes new head
        temp->next = head->next; // successor of old head becomes successor of new head
        head->next = temp;       // new head becomes succesor of old head
        anySwapped = true;
    }

    // continue until predecessor of tail is found
    ListElement *prev = head;
    while ( prev->next != nullptr && prev->next->next != nullptr )
    {
        ListElement *a = prev->next;
        ListElement *b = a->next;
        if ( a->value < b->value )
        {
            swap( prev, a, b );
            anySwapped = true;
        }
        prev = prev->next; // step one forward
    }

    return anySwapped;
}
```

Note that `(doswap= true)` is an assignment. The loop `while (doswap= true)` is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is how the nodes are currently arranged, before the swap:

```
prev --> a --> b
```

Also, assuming this is how the nodes are supposed to be after the swap:

```
prev --> b --> a
```

If the above is what the swap is supposed to change, then the code
in your swap function needs to save what node "b" has as its next
pointer:

```
void List::swap(ListElement * prev, ListElement * a, ListElement * b)
{
     ListElement * temp = b->next;
     prev->next = b;
     b->next = a;
     a->next = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is reverse the list
i have do something like that. . .

```
void LinkList::ReverseList()
{
    int Length=0;
    current=Head;
    while (current!=NULL)
    {

        current=current->link;
        Length++;

    }

    cout<<"Length is:"<<Length<<endl;
    Prev=current=Head;
    Temp=Head;
    Temp=Temp->link;
    for (int i= 0; i<Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (i==0)
        {
            Prev=Temp;
            current->link=NULL;
            Temp=Temp->link;
            Prev->link=current;
            current=Prev;

        }
        else
        {
            Prev=Temp;
            if (Temp->link!=NULL)
           {
              Temp=Temp->link;
           }

               Prev->link=current;
             current=Prev;

        }


    }
    Head=current;
}
```

Comment: In the first while loop just print the value  in the linklist.